# Como guardar en variables un archivo JSON

Tags: c#, json

estoy con un programa que recoge datos de un JSON.
Y mi pregunta es la siguiente.
Teniendo este archivo

```
  {
    "codcli": "       2",
    "nomcli": "SPORTI, S.A.",
    "codrep": "       4",
    "telcli": "93.222.11.23",
    "e_mail": "comercial@sporti.es"
  },
  {
    "codcli": "       3",
    "nomcli": "DEPORTES REUNIDOS, S.L.",
    "codrep": "       1",
    "telcli": "91.234.11.33",
    "e_mail": "comercial@reunidos.es"
  },
  {
    "codcli": "       4",
    "nomcli": "ANDA-ANDA, S.A.",
    "codrep": "       2",
    "telcli": "93.234.23.23",
    "e_mail": "comercial@andaanda.es"
  }
```

Como puedo guardar en la variable codigo el valor de codcli, en la variable nombre el valor de nomcli y asi sucesivamente.
Estoy en C#
Tengo una funcion que hacer un insert en una BBDD al pasarle unos parametros

El resultado de esto seria:

```
string codigo = "2";
string nombre = "SPORTI, S.A.";
string representante = "4";
string telefono = "93.222.11.23";
string email = "comercial@sporti.es";
cliente.Añadir(codigo, nombre, representante, telefono, email);

string codigo = "3";
string nombre = "DEPORTES REUNIDOS, S.L.";
string representante = "1";
string telefono = "91.234.11.33";
string email = "comercial@reunidos.es";
cliente.Añadir(codigo, nombre, representante, telefono, email);

string codigo = "4";
string nombre = "ANDA-ANDA, S.A.";
string representante = "2";
string telefono = "93.234.23.23";
string email = "comercial@andaanda.es";
cliente.Añadir(codigo, nombre, representante, telefono, email);
```

Como puedo conseguir ese resultado?

Comment: Por favor, explica mejor el problema con mas detalle

Comment: Podrías compartir el json completo? A lo que entiendo es que necesitas desearilizar el json a clases c#

Comment: ya he puesto lo que necesito perdonadme

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer lo siguiente, creas una clase con la estructura de los datos que tiene cada "fila" del json.

```
public class Datos
    {
        public int codcli { get; set; }
        public string nomcli { get; set; }
        public int codrep { get; set; }
        public string telcli { get; set; }
        public string e_mail { get; set; } 
    }
```

Luego deserializar el json en una lista que contendra los datos con ese tipo de clase:

```
List<Datos> listDatos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Datos>>(json);
```

Y finalmente recorres la lista y realizas las acciones que requieras:

```
foreach(Datos fila in listDatos) {
         cliente.Añadir(fila.codcli, fila.nomcli, fila.codrep, fila.telcli, fila.e_mail);
}
```